# Calculating $|A-B|$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What givens are

$$2|A| = 3|B| = 6|A\cap B|$$

$$|A\cup B| = 28$$

I want to find

$$|A - B| = ?$$

Might I get help? I'm so confused right now and don't know where to start.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is $s$ ? "size" ?

Comment: What do you mean? I mean $s$ = the sum of element numbers. Should I remove that?

Comment: Is it clear now? I've edited.

Comment: I have replaced your symbology with the standard symbol for the size of a set.

Comment: See [Inclusion–exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Comment: @StellaBiderman Thanks a lot =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x=|A\cap B|$. Then 
$$|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|.$$

$|A∪B|=28$ . Since $2|A|=3|B|=6|A∩B|=6x$, we must have that $|A|=3x$ and $|B|=2x$. This is because $2|A|=6x$, which gives $|A|=3x$ and $3|B|=6x$, which gives $|B|=2x$.

Therefore 
$$28=3x+2x-x\,.$$

You will find $x=7$. Thus $|A|=21$, $|B|=14$ and $|A\cap B|=7$. So $|A-B|=14$.

Comment: Can you be more clear at $|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|$ this part? I couldn't get how we found $x=7$ perfectly.

Comment: $|A\cup B|=28$. Since $2|A|=3|B|=6|A\cap B|=6x$, we must have that $|A|=3x$ and $|B|=2x$. So $28=3x+2x-x$. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks, got it now ;)

Comment: Also why can't $|A|$ be $2$?

Comment: If $|A|=2$, then $|B|=\frac{4}{3}$ and $|A\cap B|=\frac{2}{3}$, which can't happen

Comment: So, you say that it must be equal to $6x$. don't you?

Comment: This comes from using $2|A|=3|B|=6|A\cap B|$

Comment: We assumed that $|A\cap B| = x$ then, It must be equal to $6x$, right?

Comment: We let $x=|A\cap B|$ at the start. $6|A\cap B| = 6x$

Comment: I still couldn't get it. The thing I couldn't get is why we can't give $A = 2$ or $B = 2$

Comment: We have $2|A|=3|B|=6|A\cap B|=6x$. Since $2|A|=6x$, $|A|=3x$, and since $3|B|=6x$, $|B|=2x$.

Comment: You are great! I got it now. Can you update your answer? It would be good if you can add this into your answer.

Comment: Ok, I'll update it

Comment: You are great! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use $$ |A\cup B|=|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|$$
to  find $|A\cap B|$ (as well as $|A|,|B|$) and then 
$$|A-B|=|A|-|A\cap B| $$
for the final result.

Answer (score 2):

The principle of inclusion-exclusion tells us that $|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|$. Your chain equality plus the fact that $|A\cup B|=28$ allows you to then calculate the size of $A,B,$ and $A\cap B$.

Then use the fact that $|A-B|=|A|-|A\cap B|$, which follows straight from the definition of set minus.